# Why my animation corrupts in Unity?

Tags: animation, unity

I created a animation for my game. It perfectly works in blender and windows 3d reader but when I tried to use it in Unity it corrupts. I scaled  armature bone by bone and interplated keyframes.  What is the problem?
Blend File:
[image]

[image: Begining of the animation]

[image: End of the animation]

[image: Problematic version of animation in Unity]
[image: Model with the armature]

Comment: It looks like the children bones don't inherit their parents transforms, but the bones are stay connected, that's why they strech in Unity. Probably you have to change the settings in the game engine.

Answer (score 2):

Unity cannot handle zero scale in animation, if you're scaling the armature or bones down to zero, you just need to instead scale them to 0.001 or not lower than unity can handle.

Animations that scale to zero will play in Unity until they reach zero, and then they will no longer be able to scale back up.

If you want an object to grow from or shrink to nothing, you should scale it down to a small size and then keyframe the visibility of the mesh to hide it completely.